# tabs appear above actionbar

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I want my activity looks like

> 1. action bar, with custom view
> 2. tabs created with NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS
> 3. tab contents

but 1,2 are switched.(Tabs appear at the top of the screen, actionbar appears below of tabs)

How can I fix this?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36191 you can see the "switched" order here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/327

apparently this is a bug..

someone posted a fix

> furyfred commented 5 days ago Hi. Just found a simple workaround.
>
> use the following in your onCreate method :
>
> View homeIcon = findViewById(android.R.id.home); ((View)
>   homeIcon.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
>
> this collapses the home button completely.
>
> PS : i'm using standard ActionBar but this should work the same